# Questions about the square root of $a$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

How to prove that there is a square root of $3$ in $\mathbb{F}_p$ if and only if $p \equiv 1 $ or $11 \pmod {12}$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you know the Legendre symbol? Quadratic reciprocity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Highlights for $\;p>3\;$:

$$\sqrt3\in\Bbb F_p\iff \exists\,x\in\Bbb F_p\;\;st.\;\;x^2=3\iff \left(\frac3p\right)=1$$

Using now [quadratic reciprocity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity) , we get that

$$\left(\frac3p\right)=\begin{cases}\;\;\left(\frac p3\right)&,\;\;p=1\pmod 4\\{}\\\!-\left(\frac p3\right)&,\;\;p=3\pmod 4\end{cases}$$

and now checking each case above, and using that $\;\left(\frac p3\right)=1\iff p=1\pmod 3$ we get what we want. For example, check that

$$p=3\pmod 4\implies \left(\frac 3p\right)=1\iff p=2=-1\pmod 3\iff$$

$$\iff p=11\pmod{12}\ldots$$

Comment: thank you very much. I am confused about some parts of your answer. Why $p=2=-1 \pmod 3$ is equivalent to $p=11 \pmod {12}$? If we take $p=2$, then $p=2 \pmod 3$ but $p = 2 \ne 11 \pmod {12}$.

Comment: $\;3=1\pmod 2\;$ so the case is trivial. In the above it is assumed $\;p>3\;$ .

Comment: thank you very much. But if $p=5$, then $p=2 \pmod 3$ and $p \ne 11 \pmod{12}$.